# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a C++ calling a C# form. It appears to work properly.
However, when I open up the C# project form designer, the following error messages pop up.
What could be wrong. The solution built and ran okay.

Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

```
Instances of this error (1)
```

1. Hide Call Stack

> at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
>   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.GetFileDocData(String fileName, FileAccess access, String createTemplate, Boolean addToHostList, Boolean nestedItem)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.GetChildDocData(String name, FileAccess access, String createTemplate)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.GetResourceDocData(CultureInfo info, FileAccess access)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.System.ComponentModel.Design.IResourceService.GetResourceReader(CultureInfo info)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ResourceCodeDomSerializer.SerializationResourceManager.GetMetadata()
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ResourceCodeDomSerializer.SerializationResourceManager.GetMetadataEnumerator()
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertiesFromResources(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object value, Attribute[] filter)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
>   at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error HRESULT E\_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component VS2012 when debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this in VS2013 ultimate I had to follow the post http://rathodkrunal.blogspot.com/2011/11/visual-studio-2010-error-hresult-efail.html

Wherein it talks about simply cleaning out Visual Studio's ItemTemplateCache and running vs with the /setup flag one time.

In case the link breaks or is otherwise unavailable here's where the cache used to be for older VS:

> You can delete the project cache at "Program Files\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache", then run "devenv
>   /setup" to build the cache again to see if it helps.

Comment: what about when i published my website in iis?