# Getting "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 to modify a VB 2013 project. Whenever I try to open my main Windows Form the "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" message happens. I can't modify the form at all. There's no code errors in debug that I can find.

I've tried several of the solutions found on the following if they looked like they applied to my situation:
[Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component VS2012 when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe)

This is only happening on one of my VB forms in the solution. The other 2 forms are working fine.

Call Stack error:

```
Instances of this error (1)  

1.   Hide Call Stack 

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Utilities.Exceptions.ThrowEFail()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.LookupTypeSymbol()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.CodeModel.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef.get_TypeKind()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.GetUrtTypeFromVsType(CodeTypeRef vsType)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.OnTypePopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.CodeTypeDeclarationPopulator.OnPopulateMembers(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.CodeDom.CodeTypeDeclaration.get_Members()
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe ?  This involved a similar situation bringing a VS2010 to a VS2012 environment.

Comment: Yes I did. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the following:
**And before deleting ProjectTemplateCache and running DevEnv/setup, have a try

Start —> Run —> regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\System32\msxml3.dll

Start —> Run —> regsvr32  %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\msxml3.dll**

This did **NOT** work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to rebuild the form as it's only one screen that is giving the error. There doesn't seem to be a good solution for this at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue all the time, close Visual Studio and delete the .sln file. Then relaunch with the .vbproj file.