# WCF update reference got error "HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

I have created a WCF application in my solution having a web MVC project already in the solution, It was working fine and i added reference to my Web project successfully but when i move the solution to my new machine now at adding or updating reference it is giving error mentioned above. I tried to repair Visual studio 2 times when i first repaired the Visual studio the error resolved but again it comes do not know why. But i again repaired the Visual studio but error not resolved. I created new solution in visual studio and added a web and wcf project added reference successfully, it means the error is specified for a specific solution. How i can resolve it Please help guys...

Comment: See that thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe?rq=1