# There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have an MVC 5 project that I am working on with EF 6.x. I am using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.4.2
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.2+27004.2006
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02556

I have a model that I created and did a migration to the database. However as I continued coding I realized that I needed a new column. I created it and then created a new migration and ran update-database. My new column is in the database so I went to my controller right clicked the controller action and then add view. I put the view name the template that I want to use and then select my model. When I click add I get the following error:

Microsoft Visual Studio
Error

There was an error running the selected code generator:

'Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.'

I can create the view without the template and model however it only seems to be the one model as I can pick others that are in the project and it will create the view on that.

Troubleshooting steps thus far:

1. I have deleted the controller and recreated.
2. Followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe#_=_)
3. Deleted Visual Studio cache
4. Deleted the .suo file Deleted the
5. .csproj.user file

Any thought to what to try next would be helpful thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add a reference to System.Data in your project (right click References -> add new reference) fixed it for me.

Realise this is a little old, but I came across this when searching for the answer.