# Couldn't install any packages .Net Framework NuGet

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-framework-version

I have a solution with a lot of projects targeting .net framework but not any with .core NuGet. The case is that, quite occasionally I started getting the following error while trying to set up any package from manage NuGet packages

> HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Did someone run into the same issue and how you managed to resolve it

Comment: Did you try solutions mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe

Answer (score 0):

Go to your `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio` folder, and you should find a folder in there called `15_{id}`. Open it, and have a look at the `ActivityLog.xml`. If you have a look in it you should find the error in there and the library that's causing it. In my case it was caused by `Microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.IVsReferenceManager2` within the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll` library.

This post helped me solve the issue then: [Msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/4eea5785-0a83-4389-89e3-209a5a4432c0/referencemanagerpackage-fails-to-install-vs-2017-community-edition?forum=vssetup)

1.Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" as Admin

2.CD into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"

3.Run "gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll"

After a restart, it all worked well.

Please Follow the Source
[referencemanagerpackage-fails-to-install-vs-2017-community-edition](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/260196/add-a-reference-raise-error-error-hresult-e-fail-h.html)