# Can't get AD Attribute using DirectoryEntry (LAPS Attribute)

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm having this issue where I can't retrieve a AD attribute via `DirectoryEntry`.
I can get it via `DirectorySearcher`, but I'm unable to get or set it via `DirectoryEntry`.

The attribute needed is `ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime` which contains a NT TimeStamp, I have read and write to this attribute.

`DirectoryEntry` C# error in console

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

I've tried using the following yet still unable to retrieve the attribute.

```
RefreshCache (string[] propertyNames);
```

EDIT:

```
ComputerPrincipal comp = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, MachineName);
DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)comp.GetUnderlyingObject();
if (de.Properties.Contains("ms-Mcs-AdmPwd") == true)
{
    string Password = (String)de.Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwd"][0];
    Password_Input.Text = Password;
    DateTime NTTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(de.Properties["ms-Mcs-AdmPwdExpirationTime"].Value));
    PasswordExpiry_Value.Text = NTTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
else
{
    Password_Input.Text = "Password not set by LAPS";
}
// down the bottom of the .cs
private static long ConvertLargeIntegerToLong(object largeInteger)
{
    var type = largeInteger.GetType();
    var highPart = Convert.ToInt32(type.InvokeMember("HighPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null));
    var lowPart = Convert.ToInt32(type.InvokeMember("LowPart", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, largeInteger, null));
    return (long)highPart << 32 | (uint)lowPart;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to set the attribute or just read it? can we see the code that this error?

Comment: I found a way to read it, but would be handy if I could also set it. See Post to updated code.

Answer (score 1):

For setting properties in the past I've used this for directoryentries

Path is the full LDAP path to the object but you can substitute `de` in your example above.
Hopefully that's enough to resolve you're issue or at least point you in a direction.

Theres also some other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe) on why you might be getting that error.

And [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0261c70f-38d6-4e0c-adbb-dc4c4399130e/error-hresult-efail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component?forum=winserverDS)

```
 public Boolean set_AD_property(string attribute_, string new_value)
    {
        this.AD_object = new DirectoryEntry(this.path_);
        this.AD_object.Properties[attribute_].Value = new_value;
        try
        {
            this.AD_object.CommitChanges();
            this.AD_object.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And for reading:

```
  public object get_AD_property(string attribute_)
    {
        try
        {
            using (this.AD_object = new DirectoryEntry(this.path_))
            {
                return this.AD_object.Properties[attribute_].Value;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException x)
        {
            return new ArgumentNullException(x.Message, x);
        }
    }
```

Although this wont work for more complex properties like "members" or "memberOf"