# C#: Error HRESULT E_FAIL returned from a call to a COM component in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#

C#: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component in Visual Studio 2015 While Adding Data Source to Rdlc report

tried all solutions from this url [Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component VS2012 when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361199/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-vs2012-whe?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

but didn't succeed. [***Here attached error image***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IENbB.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do?  A RDLC is HTML format so you can open with a text editor to see the source.  The Queries are in COMMAND_TEXT tags.  So make sure the queries work in SQL Server Management Studio.  The command text is html so some special character like & have to be changed from &amp; to test in SSMS.

Comment: i'm trying to add  Data source object to rdlc report viewer it give me above error.But i added a new project in that solutions and my problem solved.Thanks alot!

Comment: It sounds like the compiler didn't recompile one of the objects.   Doing a clean build would of solved the issue.  The dependencies in the compiler doesn't always recognize changes to Net Library.