# Connect to SLDAP server V3 by using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, azure-active-directory, ldap

I have one issue when trying to connect to the LDAP server through code. It works fine when I use admin tool to connect to it.

[image: admin tool]

it works fine when using this admin tool to connect to it.
it doesn't work when I use this code to connect to it, it says
**The server could not be contacted. ---> System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.**
My code:

```
Using context As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext = New DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, SingleSignOn.ADDomain, SingleSignOn.ADSecurityGroup, DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer Or DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextOptions.Negotiate, UserName, Password)

                    Using foundUser = DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, UserName)
                        Return foundUser IsNot Nothing
                    End Using

                End Using
```

My question is:
how to **set up the code to use version 3**?
Thank you in advance for your help/ideas.

Comment: It's possible that the certificate isn't trusted by Windows (and LDAP Admin doesn't care). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62895231/1202807) for instructions on how to check the certificate.

Comment: when I run that bat script, it says '$webRequest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @GabrielLuci when I use this tool, first it shows this message https://prnt.sc/22hg100; saying the certificate is self-signed.... after hitting the Yes button it connects ...

Comment: It's not a batch file, it's a PowerShell script. You need to run it in a PowerShell window. The certificate is definitely your problem then.

Answer (score 0):

Windows needs to trust the SSL certificate, otherwise the connection will fail. Unfortunately the error message doesn't tell you that.

You have a couple options:

1. Change the certificate being used on the server to a certificate from a trusted root authority. This is the best way to do it, especially if this is a production server.
2. Tell Windows to trust the self-signed cert. This would have to be done on every computer that will connect. To do this, use the PowerShell script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62895231/1202807) to download the certificate (change the URL to match your server). This will give you a .cer file. Then follow the instructions [here](https://support.kaspersky.com/CyberTrace/1.0/en-US/174127.htm#:%7E:text=To%20start%20the%20certificate%20import%20process%20through%20Microsoft%20Management%20Console%20(MMC)) to import it on the computer that you are running this code on. In that article, start at the heading "To start the certificate import process through Microsoft Management Console (MMC)". In step 4, you have the option to import it for the current user only, or for the whole computer (which requires local admin rights).

Comment: I did it,
https://prnt.sc/22huwxc
but getting the same exception.  :/

Comment: Double-click on the .cer file. Does it say that it is trusted or does it show you a red error?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/22hw9pq this is it; 
and under the details tab it says :https://prnt.sc/22hwf0g

Comment: That looks right. Maybe you need to reboot? I'm not sure.

Comment: Did you install the cert for "My user account" or the "Computer account"?

Comment: Computer Account. Is that correct?

Comment: btw I have another output from WireShark, previously I had retransmission, now I have this : 

52945 [RST, ACK] Seq=2469 Ack=181 Win=0 Len=0 ----- marked with red.

Comment: Computer account is fine. Best I can suggest is to reboot if you haven't already. Seems odd. It should work.

Comment: weird, I am getting the exception again :
https://codeshare.io/EBJObP

Comment: any idea what it could be?

Comment: Not really... unless it just doesn't like the self-signed cert, even if it's trusted. Does LDAP Admin still give you an error?

Comment: when using this LDAP admin tool http://www.ldapadmin.org/docs/index.html
and choosing version 3, it is able to connect. 
any idea how to switch to it (v3) from the code?

Comment: I didn't find any constructor for New DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext
where version can be explicitly specified?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240016/discussion-between-loverbugs-and-gabriel-luci).

Comment: the AD is actually hosted on Azure