# TLS 1.2 works with LdapConnection but not DirectoryEntry

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am unable to connect to Active Directory with TLS 1.2 using the DirectoryService class.  I am able to connect using TLS 1.2 via LDP on Windows, Open Source LDAPAdmin on Windows and LdapConnection in a .Net 4.7.2 console application.  I have verified the TLS 1.2 connections using WireShark.  Here is some sample code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection("server.domain.com:636");
    var op = conn.SessionOptions;
    op.ProtocolVersion = 3;
    op.SecureSocketLayer = true;
    op.VerifyServerCertificate = (ldapConnection, serverCertificate) =>
    {
        return true;
    };

    conn.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
    var cred = new NetworkCredential("user@domain.com", "password");
    conn.Credential = cred;
    conn.Bind(cred);
    Console.WriteLine("LdapConnection Success");

    // Is not TLS 1.2
    var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.domain.com", "user@domain.com", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    try
    {
        foreach (var child in de.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} {ex.Message}");
    }

    //Does not work
    de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.domain.com:636", "user@domain.com", "password");
    try
    {
        foreach (var child in de.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} {ex.Message}");
    }

    //Does not work
    de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.domain.com", "user@domain.com", "password", AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    try
    {
        foreach (var child in de.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} {ex.Message}");
    }

    //Does not work
    de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.domain.com:636", "user@domain.com", "password", AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer | AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
    try
    {
        foreach (var child in de.Children)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(child);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} Success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{de.Path} {ex.Message}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Any Idea's how to connect through the DirectoryService class?  I have seem many questions about this topic in StackOverflow which is why I included all of the other answers I read about in the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to connect via LDAPS with `DirectoryEntry` is:

```
e = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.domain.com:636", "user@domain.com", "password");
```

You don't need to specify `AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer`, since that's the only possible way to connect on port 636, but it also doesn't hurt anything if you do.

My guess is that you have a problem with the certificate. Probably one of two reasons:

1. The domain name on the certificate does not match the domain name you are using to connect. For example, if you are connecting using the domain name `server.domain.com`, then the certificate must be issued to (or have a Subject Alternative Name for) `server.domain.com`. If the domain on the certificate is just `domain.com`, or just `server`, then it does not match and it will fail.
2. The certificate is not issued by an authority that the client computer trusts. It could be self-signed, for example.

It works with `LdapConnection` because you have this:

```
op.VerifyServerCertificate = (ldapConnection, serverCertificate) =>
{
    return true;
};
```

That's your custom code for validating the certificate, which always returns `true`. So *any* issue with the cert will be ignored. `DirectoryEntry` does not give you a way to do that.

You can use the PowerShell code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62895231/1202807) to download the certificate (make sure to change the domain name) and inspect it. Windows will flag an issue with it (if there is one) when you double-click the .cer file.

Comment: So even though LDAPAdmin works and the server is it's own CA, it appears the cert has chain errors.  Strange that both LDAPAdmin and LDP work but when I run my own Certificate Monitoring software, I see the chain error.  Thank for pointing me to test the certs again.  That is a real bummer there is no way to expose the error to end-users.  It makes the API almost unusable.

Comment: While sniffing packets, LDAPAdmin is able to connect TLS 1.2 on port 389.  When I try to force the port using the DirectoryServices API, the API does not attempt to communicate TLS.  Is there a way to get the TLS working on port 389 with DirectoryServices?