# directorysearcher with ldaps (ldap ssl) error COMException on connect

Tags: c#, ssl, ldap, certificate

Hi I'm not able to query our test vm with ldaps.
I switched from PrincipalContext to LdapConnection, and now trying
DirectoryEntry with no success. The Certificate we made I tried to install on my pc, but I always got :
0x80005000
as an comexception. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

```
            //test:
        string domainName2 = @"ldaps://vm-dc-test.testdomain.local"; 
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(domainName2 + ":636");
        de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
        de.Username = @"ADTest";
        de.Password = @"hiddenpw";
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        
        string filter2 = "(&(objectCategory=Group))";
 
        SearchResultCollection testResult= searcher.FindAll();  //error 
      
        foreach(var group in  testResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(group.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: My guess is that the certificate isn't being trusted on your computer. `DirectoryEntry` doesn't tell you that. Look at this answer to help you get the cert and open it to see if it's trusted on the computer you are running this code on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62895231/1202807